# User Defined Html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-defined

I created a filterable DropDown list Using JavaScript. I designed this control using input field, button (Down Arrow) and Select Box with fixed size. If i click down arrow button i'll place the select box  under the Input Field. But i want to create the whole controls as a single control. I want to create a own tag for this dropdown list. To show this dropdown list i need to simple call my own tag like

```
<dropcombo id="xxx" >
   <op>1</op>
   <op>2</op>
</dropcombo>
```

Here Dropcombo tag is a user defined control. 
Is there a way to create a own tag for this dropdown combo ?

Comment: well, can't you just not add an event handler on the type dropcombo and then do the stuff that you wnat?

Comment: I recommend you to follow what @FAngel just said

Answer (score 2):

The problem with custom HTML tags is that you'll need to use CSS to tell the browser how to render them (as the browser is unaware of how they should look).

```
<html>
<body>
    <customTag>This is my custom tag</customTag>
</body>
```

will render as:

```
This is my custom tag
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211394/when-to-use-custom-html-tags for further approaches to solving this problem.

Also, jQuery UI has [an `.autocomplete()` ui extender](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) which I recommend you check out.

Answer (score 1):

create your tag

```
dropcombo
{
display:block;
text-align:left;
/* ADD CSS PROPERTY ACCORDING TO YOUR REQUIRDMENT */
}
op
{
/* SAME HERE CSS PROPERTY */
}
```